# Regex - so close, yet so far away

Tags: python, regex

Here is my current regex: `(?:ht|f)tps?:[\S]*\/?(?:\w+)`

I need to refine it such that it pulls the following link correctly from the quoted text below: `http://www.purdue.edu/transcom/index.php`

Any thoughts on how I can improve my current regex? Thanks in advance!

> Additional information about the experimental protocol and results is
>   provided in the companion files and the TransCom project web site
>   (http://www.purdue.edu/transcom/index.php).The results of the Level 1
>   experiments presented here are grouped into two broad categories

Comment: I suppose you want to find any link, not just this specific one, right?

Comment: Try this: [`\(((?:ht|f)tps?:[\S]*\/?(?:\w+))\)` and retrieve group 1](https://regex101.com/r/nSNurX/1).

Comment: @eukaryota correct, find any link embedded in any text :)

Comment: @Idlehands unfortunately that pulls with the parentheses. i'll be doing a response code test on the link, so i would need the entire link without the parentheses.

Comment: As you can see from StackOverflow's failed attempt to parse your URL, doing so isn't easy...

Comment: @coding_patty that's why I said retrieve group 1... it's matching the link within the parentheses and then returning the result *without* the parentheses.

Comment: The first answer at the duplicate is able to properly parse your example.

Answer (score 0):

I do not tested your regex thougoutly, and this is not clear enough why is your current regex failing.
But to catch a ulr in general, I would use the repetition of the group (the authorized characters for html minus the slash like [a-zA-Z0-9.]) and the slash)
something like

```
r'(?:ht|f)tps?:\\(?:\\[_html_authorized_chars])*'
```

and eventually a positive lookahead assertion if the answer is always inside quotes or parenthesis...

Answer (score 0):

> **Url Similar Splitter**
>
> matches url similars and splits it into its address and parameters
>
> *by deme72*

`([--:\w?@%&+~#=]*\.[a-z]{2,4}\/{0,2})((?:[?&](?:\w+)=(?:\w+))+|[--:\w?@%&+~#=]+)?`

Source: [regexr.com community](http://regexr.com/3ajfi)